# give access to file outside www/html folder

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have LAMP server

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

PHP: PHP 7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

I need to give an php SQLITE3 access to db outside www/html folder.
Right now my filesystem looks this way.

```
/root
    ./database
        user.db
/var
    ./www
        ./html
            index.html
            reg.php
```

user.db must be located in /root/database, so just putting it inside var/www/html isn't solution for me.

So I need to give access to this folder for Apache or php.
I found some information here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html, but didn't get how this works and where I need to put this?

Comment: I would just create a symlink from `/root/database/` to your `var/www/html` directory.

Comment: @fyroc I symlinked, but nothing happened. However it looks progressive way. When i type in browser http://example.com/db/helloworld.html it recognize, this URL exist, but answer with 403 HTTP code `Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /db/helloworld.html on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at examle.com Port 80` How I can grant access to it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is Linux permissions, not URL mapping, as PHP is running in the server, in the backend.

If you run PHP as an Apache module, (`mod_php` or something like that), it will run with the Apache user and group (usually `www-data:www-data` or `nobody:nogroup`, it depends of the LAMP configuration).

So, you should give permissions and change ownership to the `user.db` file and its tree, something like:

```
chmod o+x /root
chmod o+x /root/database
chown www-data:www-data /root/database/user.db
```

You can read more about permissions [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).

Comment: will other app running by root user also have access to DB after this action?

Comment: Root have access to everything :-) The problem is with the other users.

Comment: How should it be modified if another user "daq" (of group daq_group) was the owner of "/root/database/user.db "? How can we give access to "www-data" without changing original ownership? Adding "daq" to "www-data" group and making "www-data" group as the owner of the directory is still not working! @drmad